Determining Suitable TRMS Voltmeter Specs for Modulated Signal Measurement
I'm seeking advice on selecting a TRMS (True RMS) voltmeter suitable for measuring the voltage across a resistor with a modulated signal. Here's the scenario:
I need to measure the TRMS voltage across a resistor to calculate its average power consumption. The signal I'm dealing with is modulated, with a carrier wave at 25.5 kHz and modulation frequencies ranging from 20 Hz to 200 Hz. The maximum peak-to-peak voltage (Vpp) is 50V. Square waves are used for both the carrier and modulating waveform
When researching TRMS multimeters online, I noticed specifications such as "frequency range" and "samples per second." For instance, some multimeters specify a frequency range in the MHz range, while others mention a certain number of samples per second (e.g., 3 samples per second).
I'm uncertain about which specific specifications are crucial for determining whether a voltmeter would be capable of accurately measuring the TRMS voltage at the frequencies mentioned above.
Any guidance on what specifications I should prioritize or what features I should be looking for in a TRMS voltmeter to ensure it's suitable for measuring the TRMS voltage of a modulated signal would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your insights

What "spectral" components do you need to measure?

Just rectify the output and measure with a "normal" TRMS voltmeter
(20 to 200 Hz will be fine for "all" voltmeters).
High-frequency would be discarded.

